# Defining newtheorems using loops

Tags: loops

I would like to define Theorem x.y say x,y are integers between 1 and 20.

Then, I need to write 400 sentences like

```
\newtheorem*{theorem1.1}{Theorem 1.1}.
```

EDIT: I'm typping some old book in a latex form which has its own theorem numbering system. To follow it, I would like to define such theorem environements a priori (using a loop sentence for example). Is there a nice way to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I am not sure I understand. Please, what you ask seem strange for me, so if you can explain your idea, what you want to do with this? may be there is better way.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Since LaTeX numbers theorems automatically, why should you want to do it by hand?

Comment: I meant that can I use a loop sentence in latex as C+ program. That's right but I want to use \begin{theorem2.5}\end{theorem2.5} right after \begin{theorem2.3}\end{theorem2.3} without using theorem2.4.

Comment: For this purpose, I would like to define theorem x.y for all x,y in {1,...,10} a priori and use them freely.

Comment: @user156937: This question is totally unclear. Defining a theorem is done with `\newtheorem`, but the numbering is done with `\begin{foo}...\end{foo}`. Your request indicates that you want to have 400 different types of theorem? What's the purpose of this?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Could I ask what is \begin{foo} \end{foo}?

Comment: @user156937: `foo` is  a placeholder for something longer, replace it with `theorem` here, just as an example

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Now I understand your comment. I editted my question. Thanks!

Comment: @user156937: Even if you want to reproduce the old book style, it might be easier to change the numbering instead of using 400 different theorems directly.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I agree but what I want to do is something like the following: \foreach \y in {1,...,30}{
\foreach \x in {1,...,10}{\newtheorem*{theorem\x.\y}{Theorem \x.\y}}
} but this doesn't work.

Comment: @user156937: you can't have numbers in macro names (or environment names) -- at least not this way

Comment: @ChristianHupfer you can have numbers in environment names it's just a bad idea to do so.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Really? I've never tried to do so. Thanks for updating me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a different strategy:

```
\newtheorem*{blurb}{Theorem \whatever}
\newcommand{\whatever}{}
\newenvironment{theorem}[1]
 {\renewcommand\whatever{#1}\begin{blurb}}
 {\end{blurb}}
```

so you can do

```
\begin{theorem}{3.25}
```

in your document.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted! Thanks a lot!